# How to make function thread safe

Tags: c++, thread-safety

This is the code where i would be inserting values in a unordererd map and would also query those values at regular intervals.

```
class MemoryMap
{
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> maps_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    


public:
    void AddMap(std::string key, std::string value);
    std::string GetMap(std::string key);
    void PrintMemoryMap(std::string key);

};



void MemoryMap::AddMap(std::string key, std::string value)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    maps_[key] = value;
    
}

std::string MemoryMap::GetMap(std::string key)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    if (maps_.find(key) == maps_.end())
        return "";
    
        return maps_.at(key);
}
```

I would be using this object in two different threads and i want when insertion would be happening through AddMap function than GetMap function should wait for the insertion to finish. Also GetMap function would be called concurrently.

Is my current code sufficient to address this issue ?

Comment: `GetMap` can be improved: `auto it = maps_.find(key); return it == maps_.end() ? "" : *it;`. (One look-up instead of 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient. The mutex lock guarantees at most one thread get call get or set at the same time.

However, your code might be not optimized if you want to achieve concurrent reads. In C++, `unordered_map` is a container, which has thread safety like this:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety Two threads can safely call `get` at the same time because it is a constant function, if no thread is modifying the container.

Comment: if i want to have concurrent reads what should i modify in my code ?

Comment: @shomit Do you have C++17? If so, you can use `std::shared_mutex` to enable concurrent reads.

Comment: @jignatius i have uptill c++14.

Comment: @shomit In that case, your implementation is fine. You do need to lock the mutex like the way you are doing since you have at least one function that modifies the map. Only if it's a read-only map you don't need to provide any thread synchronization yourself.

Comment: @jignatius i am also writing to the map as well as i will have concurrant reads from the map  , do i need mutex in this case ?

Comment: @shomit Yes, definitely you do. You could use `std::lock_guard` instead of `std::unique_lock` because you're not making use of the latter's extra features. `std::lock_guard` is also less expemsive.